# How can I prevent data in my network from hopping via the router, instead of using only the switch?

Tags: networking, router, switch, gigabit-ethernet

In my home network, I have a regular broadband router, connected via a powerline adapter to a gigabit switch, which in turn is connected to my desktop and home server.

The router assigns static IP addresses to the desktop and server, i.e. the DHCP server on the router is reserving their addresses. Both desktop and server are on the same subnet, and the subnet mask is 255.255.255.0

Sometimes, transferring data from the desktop to the server is so slow, it seems to hop via the router. This is further supported by the observation that, previously, when a wireless bridge was used instead of a powerline adapter to connect the switch to the router, transfer speeds were much slower still.

Disabling / re-enabling the ethernet adapter on the desktop fixes this problem, temporarily. I cannot reliably recreate this issue though.

**How can I ensure that the switch always hands packets from the desktop directly to the server, instead of sending them on a round trip to the router first?**

Technical specifications:

- Router: Virgin Media Superhub 2ac
- Powerline adapter: TP-LINK TL-PA411KIT AV500 500 Mbps Nano
- Switch: TP-Link TL-SG1005D
- Desktop: Windows 7, Realtek PCIe GBE
- Server: HP proliant n40l, CentOS

Comment: Local traffic doesn't transit your router. If it does then you have your hosts or the physical network configured incorrectly. There are a litany of possible causes but the router isn't one of them.

Comment: This is really a bunch of sole low-end poorly designed and badly assembled equipment, and this may be the root cause of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Excluding hardware failures (that, in case, we cannot resolve), the problem may be caused by a wrong network configuration.

What do you mean by

> The router assigns static IP addresses to the desktop and server.

?

Do you mean that you configured the DHCP server running on the router to **reserve** some IPs for the desktop PC and for the server?
If this is the case DHCP should also configure the other network parameters, like default gateway and network mask.

**Network mask** in particular is crucial in your scenario, since based on it both the server and the desktop decide to route packets.

Please, check the IP assigned and network mask on both machines:

for Windows command prompt

```
ipconfig
```

for CentOS terminal

```
ifconfig
```

If the network mask is something like 255.255.255.0 and the assigned IP addresses are like 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.3 you are fine, but if you have something like 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.0.3 it's not supposed to work, since everyone will try to passs through the router in order to reach the other machine.

If you can provide more details (e.g. output from the commands above) we could try to help you better! :)

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time for such a detailed response. Yes, the DHCP is reserving those IP addresses, and the network mask is 255.255.255.0 on both devices, and they are on the same subnet- 192.168.0.18 and 192.168.0.27. I wasn't aware that it could work at all if this wasn't the case, so this is handy to know. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: Could you try to `traceroute 192.168.0.18` from .27 and `traceroute 192.168.0.27` from .18?

Consider that on Windows Command Prompt you need to use `tracert`, `traceroute` is for UNIX.